# Portable Ubuntu, how to auto install the correct ATI/Nvidia driver when booting?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, graphics, fglrx

That is. **I don't want to have both drivers installed at the same time**. I just want to make an init script or whatever which will choose the correct driver for the video card currently installed during the boot.

I don't think that this is impossible with the *nix ideology that everything is the file. Roughly, I think that should be possible to pack all driver-related files into two archives, `amd.tar` and `nvidia.tar` do `lspci` before video driver is loaded and extract the needed one to the root filesystem.

The reason why I need this is that I have a portable installation of the ubuntu which works well on every machine whichever I tried. The only issue with it is in fact that I need to reinstall drivers manually from the recovery mode everytime I use the computer with the graphical card different to the previous one.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between having them "installed" and having them as a .tar ?

Having them "installed" is going to be easier as it then allows the kernel to select the correct driver and load the necessary driver as a kernel module, so, other then making a custom spin, your work is done.

Using an archive or tar may save some space, depending on the compression, but you will have to write a script. The script, and all necessary archives, would need to be in the initramfs, including the archives.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs.

Support for custom kernels and custom initramfs is somewhat limited here. If you have a specific question with a specific step of the process you might get an answer.

Comment: You should know that it's impossible to have both fgltx and nvidia drivers installed at the same time. Actually when you try to install nvidia, it will detect that fglrx installed and will make some changes in its files which make fglrx unusable.

Comment: I've not tried it. The behavior you describe would be a bug report, but I am not sure how much interest there is, but the drivers should in theory be able to co-habitate. What are " some changes in its files" ? changes to the initramfs ?

Comment: Not only initramfs, but opengl libraries are conflicting between these two packages.

Comment: I do not have direct experience and you have not provided any details other then to state you have having a problem Take a look as how other distros solve this problem, Sabayon perhaps.

Comment: Could you please provide a manual how to install both drivers on sabayon together? I haven't googled anything about it.

Comment: I have no idea how Sabayon does this, if I did I would just post the solution here.